# Can't move file after DownloadManager completes download

Tags: java, android, apache-commons, android-download-manager

in my Android app I am using the system Download Manager to download a photo, once recieved I process it and then I need to move it to another location. if I just copy it it works fine, if I try to move it/delete it I get an exception about it can't be moved.

```
Failed to delete original file '/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/a3133p2930-9.jpg' after copy to '/data/data/com.XXXXX.testharness/app_appdata/images/one/two/three/6/a3133p2930.jpg'
```

also tried:

1) remove it from download manager before trying to move it
2) set the destination directly to the target dir, but got an error I can only use public external folders.
3) tried using JAVA renameTo and Apache commons moveFile

this is a code snippet that show the relevant parts of what I am doing.

any ideas?

appreciated

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {


    String uriString = c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndex(
                                DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));


    String uri2String = c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndex(
                                    DownloadManager.COLUMN_URI));

    String localFileString = c.getString(
                                c.getColumnIndex(
                                        DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));

    File from = new File(localFileString);
    File to = new File(appDataDir, localString);
    File to2 = new File (appDataDir, localString + "/" + getFileNameFromUrl(uri2String));


    if (!to.exists()) {
        if (to.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(LCAT, "Directory  Created");
            }
        }
    dm.remove(downloadId);

    //boolean a = from.renameTo(to2);

    try { 
        FileUtils.copyFile(from, to2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LCAT, "rename success? " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you can not delete the cache of `downloadmanager`, i think it clears itself automatically after you removed the downloadid from its database but if you like to have a control to your file you can set destination folder to your private external storage and then after download completed delete it.

```
File rootDirectory = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsoluteFile().toString());
if(!rootDirectory.exists()){
   rootDirectory.mkdirs();
}  
req.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity(),null ,"/" + fileName);
```

and after your download completed you can delete it like:

```
 from.delete();
```

and the doc says:

> public int remove (long... ids)
>
> Cancel downloads and remove them from
> the download manager. Each download will be stopped if it was running,
> and it will no longer be accessible through the download manager. If
> there is a downloaded file, partial or complete, it is deleted.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#remove%28long...%29